# Can attackers bypass Ajax Form with JavaScript switched off

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a form on my website with all the validation done on jQuery and PHP and sanitizing done by PHP of user information's. A quick question came into my mind.

Can a attacker (Hacker) bypass Ajax Form with JavaScript Switched Off?

**Here is the HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post" id="form-contact-us" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" id="action" name="action" value="contact">
<input type="text" class="hide" value="" name="challenge" id="challenge">
<div class="col-md-6 mt-10">
    <label>Your Full Name&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your Full Name">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 mt-10">
    <label>Your Email Address&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email Address">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 mt-10">
    <label>Phone Contact</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Contact">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 mt-10">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="col-md-6 band mt-10">
    <label for="firstname">Your Message&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="message" name="message"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="btn-group band">
    <span id="loader"></span>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-right: 14px; border-radius: 0px;">SEND <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></button>
</div>
    </form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("form#form-contact-us").on("submit", function (){
    var form, challenge, name, email, phone, message;
    form = $("form#form-contact-us").serialize();
    challenge = $("#challenge").val();
    name = $("form#form-contact-us #name").val();
    email = $("form#form-contact-us #email").val();
    phone = $("form#form-contact-us #phone").val();
    message = $("form#form-contact-us #message").val();

    challenge = $.trim(challenge);
    name = $.trim(name);
    email = $.trim(email);
    phone = $.trim(phone);
    message = $.trim(message);

    $("div#msg").removeClass("alert alert-danger alert-success").html("");

    if( challenge.length > 0 ){
        return false;
    } else if( !name || !email || !message ){
        $("div#msg").fadeIn("fast").addClass("alert alert-danger").html("All the fields marked with * is required.");
    } else if( !mask2.test(name) ){
        $("div#msg").fadeIn("fast").addClass("alert alert-danger").html("Your full name format is invalid.");
    } else if( !mask5.test(email) ){
        $("div#msg").fadeIn("fast").addClass("alert alert-danger").html("Your email address format is invalid.");
    } else if( name.length < 3 ){
        $("div#msg").fadeIn("fast").addClass("alert alert-danger").html("Your full name cannot be less then 3 letters.");
    } else if( email.length < 5 ){
        $("div#msg").fadeIn("fast").addClass("alert alert-danger").html("Your email address cannot be less then 5 letters.");
    } else if( phone != "" && !mask4.test(phone) || phone.length < 7 || phone.length > 11 ){
        $("div#msg").fadeIn("fast").addClass("alert alert-danger").html("Please enter your phone number.");
    } else if( message.length < 5 ){
        $("div#msg").fadeIn("fast").addClass("alert alert-danger").html("Your message cannot be less then 5 letters.");
    } else {
        $("#form-contact-us .btn-primary ").text("Please Wait...").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#form-contact-us .btn-primary").addClass("disabled");
        jQuery.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: form,
            success:function(data){
                var data = data.split("|");
                var code = $.trim(data[0]);
                var msg = $.trim(data[1]);
                if( code == 1 ){
                    $("div#msg").fadeIn("fast").addClass("alert alert-success").html(msg);
                    $("#form-contact-us").fadeOut("fast");
                } else {
                    $("div#msg").fadeIn("fast").addClass("alert alert-danger").html(msg);
                     $("#form-contact-us .btn-primary ").text("SEND <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right\"></span>").attr('disabled', true);
                }
                $("#form-contact-us #loader").html("");
                $("#form-contact-us .btn-primary").removeClass("disabled");
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

**PHP**

```
function contact(){
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
        if(isset($_POST["challenge"]) && trim($_POST["challenge"]) == ""){
            $name = $_POST["name"];
            $email = $_POST["email"];
            $phone = $_POST["phone"];
            $message = $_POST["message"];

            $name = trim($name);
            $email = trim($email);
            $phone = trim($phone);
            $message = trim($message);

            if( empty($name) or empty($email) or empty($email) or empty($phone) or empty($message)){
                die("0 | All the fields marked with * is required.");
            } else if ( !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/', $name)){
                die("0 | Your full name format is invalid.");
            } else if ( strlen($name) < 3 ){
                die("0 | Your full name cannot be less then 3 letters.");
            } else if ( !is_email($email) ){
                die("0 | Your email address format is invalid.");
            } else if ( strlen($email) < 5 ){
                die("0 | Your email address cannot be less then 5 letters.");
            } else if ( !empty($phone) and strlen($phone) < 7 or strlen($phone) > 11 ){
                die("0 | Please enter your phone number.");
            } else if ( strlen($message) < 5 ){
                die("0 | Your message cannot be less then 5 letters.");
            } else if ( check_for_spam($name) > 0 ){
                die("0 | Please remove any links from your full name.");
            } else if ( check_for_spam($phone) > 0 ){
                die("0 | Please remove any links from What would you like to know phones.");
            } else if ( check_for_spam($message) > 0 ){
                die("0 | Please remove any links from your message.");
            } else {
                $name = sanitize_text_field($name);
                $email = sanitize_text_field($email);
                $phone = sanitize_text_field($phone);
                $message = sanitize_text_field($message);

                $name = remove_html($name);
                $email = remove_html($email);
                $phone = remove_html($phone);
                $message = remove_html($message);

                $name = esc_html($name);
                $email = esc_html($email);
                $phone = esc_html($phone);
                $message = esc_html($message);

                /* All Good */

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Depends on what you have for code that could be potentially lethal.

Comment: In what context? Where do you do the validation? Server side (PHP/ASP/etc) or client side (javascript/jQuery) ?

Comment: Validation both on PHP and JavaScript and sanitizing PHP Side

Comment: I think your question would best be suited for Code Review http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and/or http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Since you are doing Server side validations as well, you are not attack prone. If they by pass your client side  validations they still have to go through your PHP validations. As long as they are secure you are reasonably safe.

Comment: @DevilRaily , please clear your code and simplify your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An attacker can send a form without using the HTML you provide him.
In your case, your form is using POST method.

```
POST /code.php

action    => contact
challenge => 
name      => a_name
email     => an_email
phone     => a_phone
message   => a_message
```

If challenge is a security token or something generated by a Javascript function, the attacker can of course emulate this function and get this ***challenge*** and submit the form.